# Filter dynamic table result using multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a stock table looks like this:

```
 Supplier  |  Category  |  ItemID  |  Stock  |  SafetyLimit  |  Status
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ABC     |  FOOD      |   001    |    200  |        140    |  Safe
   ABC     |  FOOD      |   004    |     50  |        100    |  Risky
   DEF     |  NON FOOD  |   002    |    150  |        100    |  Safe
   DEF     |  FOOD      |   006    |     32  |         50    |  Risky
```

I'm trying to make 3 filters for that table based on Supplier (All, ABC, DEF), Category (All, Food, Non-Food), and Status (Safe, Risky). I found this script:

```
$('select').change(function () {
   var current = this.value;
   if (current == 'all') {
      $('#FilterContainer').find('div.all').show();
   } else {
      $('#FilterContainer').find('div').hide();
      $('#FilterContainer').find('div.all.' + current).show();
   }
   return false;
});
```

working perfectly from this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5DpP/), but in my case, my table isn't static. It's data get populated dynamically. Would anyone help me please with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your data structure, but if it is populated dynamically you can do something like this.

First, find unique values for each filters:

```
// Example for suppliers
const suppliers = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF'];  // Your suppliers data
const uniqueSuppliers = Array.from(new Set(suppliers));  // ['ABC', 'DEF']
const supplierFilterValues = ['All', ...uniqueSuppliers];  // ['All', 'ABC', 'DEF']
```

Now user can choose from `supplierFilterValues` to filter data, for example user want to show only rows with 'DEF' supplier:

```
const tableData = [{
    supplier: 'ABC',
    category: 'FOOD',
    itemID: '001',
    stock: '200',
    safetyLimit: '140',
    status: 'Safe',
}, {
    supplier: 'DEF',
    category: 'NON FOOD',
    itemID: '002',
    stock: '150',
    safetyLimit: '100',
    status: 'Safe',
}];
const dataToShow = tableData.filter((item) => item.supplier === 'DEF');
```